# Search and filtering not working as it should in my flask application

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, flask

I have created an application in flask, therein I am displaying a csv file using python's tablib library.
I basically wanted to apply a search and filter operation on the csv file. So, for instance if a user searches for "My company name" only relevant options should be shown on the csv file. But what happens is that after searching for "My company name" the page stays the same and if I search something other like "jcfndofof" then I get a blank csv file(which is what I want). But the same doesn't apply when I want to search for specific name.

Here is my code for the same.

```
    <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#ser").on("keyup", function() {
                        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
                        $("#log ").filter(function() {
                            $(this).toggle($(this).text()
                            .toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
                        });
                    });
                });
    
    <b> Search the table:
            <input id="ser" type="text" placeholder="Search here"></b>
    <div id="log">
          {% block body %}
          {{ files|safe }}
          {% endblock %}
            </div>
```

To sum it up: If I want to search "company name" only that particular name should come up and nothing else. If I search for something other which is not in the file it should go blank(which it goes as expected.)

Please help.

**EDIT**: Added a few screenshots of what contains in log id and flask function

```
@app.route('/')
def display():
    files = files_date.export("html")
    return render_template('index.html', files=files)
```

```
[before searching][1]
[searching the correct name- only that name should be shown not any other][2]
[searching for a name that doesn't exist- this works fine][3]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6y1k.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIo4Z.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eF5Km.png
```

Comment: Hi, can you show output of htmls inside `<div id="log">` ?

Comment: @Swati I have edited my question, please have a look

Comment: *output of htmls inside <div id="log">..* in text i mean to say .

Comment: not sure what you mean by that but this might be what you wanted to know? ```<div id="log">
          {% block body %}
          {{ files|safe }}
          {% endblock %}
            </div> ``` the 'files' in this is being added from flask

Comment: check if [this](https://jsfiddle.net/62b54zt9/) works for you .

Comment: @Swati That is exactly what I intend to get..however that is hardcoded by you..whereas I  am getting all the records(column names as well as their records) at once in my div id

Comment: go inside browsers elements tab and copy whole html inside `<div id="log">` and paste in your asked question so that it would more easy to create working demo .